# @Provider resource not registering in rest application

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am trying to register an interceptor for my rest application. The purpouse of this interceptor is to get a token inside the request to validate if the request is valid or not.

I have created a custom tag to achieve this:

```
@Provider
@Secured
public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter{

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(AuthenticationFilter.class);

UserDAO userDAO = (UserDAO) SpringApplicationContext.getBean("userDAO");

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

    // Get the HTTP Authorization header from the request
    String authorizationHeader = 
        requestContext.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

    // Check if the HTTP Authorization header is present and formatted correctly 
    if (authorizationHeader == null || !authorizationHeader.startsWith("BSC")) {
        if (authorizationHeader== null){
            LOGGER.error("No authorization header");
        } else{
            LOGGER.error("Authorization header: " + authorizationHeader);
        }
        throw new NotAuthorizedException("Authorization header must be provided");
    }

    // Extract the token from the HTTP Authorization header
    String token = authorizationHeader.substring("BSC".length());
    // Validate the token
    boolean ok = validateToken(token);

    if (!ok){
        LOGGER.error("Not authorized, passed token: " + token);
        throw new NotAuthorizedException("Not authorized");
    }


}

private boolean validateToken(String token){
    boolean ok = userDAO.validateToken(token);
    if (ok){
        userDAO.updateToken(token);
    }else{
        userDAO.deleteToken(token);
    }

    return ok;
}
```

}

```
@NameBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface Secured { 

}
```

All of the methods with the @Secured tag must pass throught the interceptor.

I have registered the interceptor and the rest service in a class that extends Application:

```
public class RestApplication extends Application{
private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();

public RestApplication() {
    singletons.add(new RestService());
    singletons.add(new AuthenticationFilter());
}

@Override
public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
    return singletons;
}
}
```

Then in my web.xml I have registered this class:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>Manufacturing</display-name>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
         <param-value>com.everis.manufacturing.application.RestApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But it not seems to work, I am calling a service that have the @Secured tag but it isn´t calling the interceptor.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try changing the class RestApplication to extend [ResourceConfig](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/2.26-b09/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html) instead of Application.

Comment: The only dependency to Jersey in my pom is jersey-server, when I try to extend ResourceConfig the only class it founds is com.sun.jersey.api.core.ResourceConfig

Comment: package names may differ between versions. you can use it if it extends Application. If it doesn't then please could you update your question with the library versions?